# SQL: Average time to complete task

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find how long on average it is taking a developer to complete his/her task based on number of tasks given in time period. I've never used the AVG() function before in SQL so i'm a bit of a newb. I have all the values to perform the function i think but not sure how to write the statement.

I think I need advice more than anything on how to approach it or some samples. I could not find anything but 'm sure there is a way to accomplish this task.

```
DECLARE
    @Date AS DATETIME = '2019-08-08 00:00:00.000',
    @Developer_Name AS VARCHAR(100) = 'Jim Bob'
--AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE 
        --Get User ID
        @UserID AS BIGINT = (SELECT usr.id FROM [dbo].[mantis_user_table] AS usr wHERE usr.realname = @Developer_Name) 

    DECLARE 
        @Resolved_30 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
        @Resolved_60 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -60, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
        @Resolved_90 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
        @Assigned_30 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
        @Assigned_60 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -60, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
        @Assigned_90 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID)

    SELECT
        @UserID,
        @Resolved_30,
        @Resolved_60,
        @Resolved_90,
        @Assigned_30,
        @Assigned_90

END
```

The expected result is a average in a percentage

Not sure would this work:

```
--Assigned / completed
        SUM(@Assigned_30 / @Resolved_30) AS 'SUM 1',
        SUM(@Assigned_60 / @Resolved_60) AS 'SUM 2',
        SUM(@Assigned_90 / @Resolved_90) AS 'SUM 3'
```

Is that the average or how i get the average?

Update:
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but getting an error:

```
    --Assigned / completed
    CASE WHEN @Resolved_30 = 0 OR @Assigned_30 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(@Assigned_30 / @Resolved_30) END AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 30 Days',
    CASE WHEN @Resolved_60 = 0 OR @Assigned_30 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(@Assigned_60 / @Resolved_60) END AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 60 Days',
    CASE WHEN @Resolved_90 = 0 OR @Assigned_30 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(@Assigned_90 / @Resolved_90) END AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 90 Days'
```

Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
Divide by zero error encountered.

I know what the error is saying but im not sure what the issue is because I'm checking for 0. Is it saying the value is NULL?

Update:
I think my average calculation is wrong:

```
Resolved_30   Assigned_30  Average Tasks Completed In 30 Days
20                 10                   2
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update:
I know my math is right but its not calculating correctly in SQL. the 30 should be 90.9%

```
DECLARE
@Date AS DATETIME = '2019-08-08 00:00:00.000',
@Developer_Name AS VARCHAR(100) = 'Jim Bob'
```

--AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        --Get User ID
        @UserID AS BIGINT = (SELECT usr.id FROM [dbo].[mantis_user_table] AS usr wHERE usr.realname = @Developer_Name)

```
DECLARE 
    @Resolved_30 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Resolved_60 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -60, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Resolved_90 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Assigned_30 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Assigned_60 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -60, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Assigned_90 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID)

SELECT
    @UserID AS 'User_ID',
    @Resolved_30 AS 'Resolved_30',
    @Resolved_60 AS 'Resolved_60',
    @Resolved_90 AS 'Resolved_90',
    @Assigned_30 AS 'Assigned_30',
    @Assigned_90 AS 'Assigned_90',
    ((@Resolved_30/@Assigned_30)*100) AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 30 Days',
    SUM((@Resolved_90/@Assigned_90)*100)AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 60 Days',
    SUM((@Resolved_90/@Assigned_90)*100) AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 90 Days'
```

END

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: in sql you want to think in sets not in singles

Comment: [This](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression) article explains how `case` may evaluate aggregate expressions before evaluating the `when` clause(s). In any event, having a `case` return a sometimes `sum` seems a bit odd. Using `case` _inside_ `sum` is quite common. As previously requested, sample data and desired results might clear up what you're actually asking for. "Tasks completed" over some period does not depend on "tasks assigned" in that period. It would not be unexpected that some tasks completed were assigned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you have to think in sets not in tradition flow of control, for example here is a way to get all 6 of those results in one query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) as Cnt, Staus, (DATEDIFF(DAY,DAY,@Date) % 30) AS PERIOD
FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug 
WHERE [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID) AND [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, @Date) AND @Date
GROUP BY (DATEDIFF(DAY,DAY,@Date) % 30), Status
```

as far as that line that gives you the error I don't know what you are doing -- you don't have a column name in there so it makes no sense to me.  I'd expect something like this

```
SUM(CASE WHEN @Resolved_30 = 0 OR @Assigned_30 = 0 
         THEN 0 
         ELSE column_you_want_to_average END) / total_value AS 'Average'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved my issue. Not the best way but worked:. I'm still not sure if Im getting the average correctly but no errors:

```
 DECLARE
    @Date AS DATETIME = '2019-08-08 00:00:00.000',
    @Developer_Name AS VARCHAR(100) = 'Deepa Nadella'
--AS

BEGIN   
    DECLARE 
        --Get User ID
        @UserID AS BIGINT = (SELECT usr.id FROM [dbo].[mantis_user_table] AS usr wHERE usr.realname = @Developer_Name), 
    @Average_30 BIGINT = 0,
    @Average_60 BIGINT = 0,
    @Average_90 BIGINT = 0

DECLARE 
    @Resolved_30 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Resolved_60 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -60, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Resolved_90 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 80 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Assigned_30 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -30, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Assigned_60 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -60, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID),
    @Assigned_90 BIGINT = (SELECT COUNT([id]) FROM [dbo].[mantis_bug_table] bug WHERE [last_updated] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -90, @Date) AND @Date AND [status] = 50 AND [reporter_id] = @UserID)

    --Average Tasks
    IF(@Resolved_30 > 0) BEGIN
        SET @Average_30 = SUM(@Assigned_30 / @Resolved_30)
    END

    IF(@Resolved_60 > 0) BEGIN
        SET @Average_60 = SUM(@Assigned_60 / @Resolved_60)
    END

    IF(@Resolved_90 > 0) BEGIN
        SET @Average_90 = SUM(@Assigned_90 / @Resolved_90)
    END

SELECT
    @UserID,
    @Resolved_30 AS 'Resolved_30',
    @Resolved_60 AS 'Resolved_60',
    @Resolved_90 AS 'Resolved_90',
    @Assigned_30 AS 'Assigned_30',
    @Assigned_90 AS 'Assigned_90',
    @Average_30 AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 30 Days',
    @Average_60 AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 60 Days',
    @Average_90 AS 'Average Tasks Completed In 90 Days'
```

END

I tried using a CASE but that kept giving me that error.

Comment: this does not make sense to me -- you are taking the count of items assigned and diving by the number completed in that time period, but the output is saying averge tasks completed in that period of time.  This is not what your calculation is doing.

Comment: Trying to figure out the average amount of tasks completed based on tasks assigned

Comment: What do you mean by "based on"  is this a ratio?  eg 200% means for every 2 tasks assigned 1 is finished?